# Github action pipeline keeps failing with Error: Az CLI Login failed. Please check the credentials and make sure az is installed on the runner

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, github-actions, pipeline

I am pretty new to github actions. the pipeline is supposed to deploy the app to azure. it runs three jobs, the first two are successful, but the last job which is the deploy phase keeps failing. it keeps bringing out this output Error:

> Az CLI Login failed. Please check the credentials and make sure az is installed on the runner. For more information refer https://aka.ms/create-secrets-for-GitHub-workflows

since both the first two jobs runs perfectly, I'll only be showing the last job here with the env

```
name: myapp

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.'      
  DOTNET_VERSION: '6.0.x'                 # set this to the .NET Core version to use

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  workflow_dispatch:
  
defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: app/myapp
    
permissions:
  contents: read



deploy: 
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: app/myapp 
    permissions:
      contents: none
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [build,access]
    if: needs.access.outputs.secrets-valid == 'true'
    environment:
      name: 'Test-QA'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app
          

      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
          enable-AzPSSession: true


      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
```

artifact download was successful, but it was throwing the this error message.

> Az CLI Login failed. Please check the credentials and make sure az is installed on the runner. For more information refer https://aka.ms/create-secrets-for-GitHub-workflows

I had to make changes by installing azure cli before the login session like o:

```
steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app
          
      - name: Install Azure cli
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl apt-transport-https lsb-release gnupg
          curl -sL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg > /dev/null
          AZ_REPO=$(lsb_release -cs)
          echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ $AZ_REPO main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install azure-cli

      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
          enable-AzPSSession: true

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
```

I got a different error displaying:

> Error: An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/bin/bash' with working directory '/runner/_work/...dir/app/myapp'. No such file or directory

I really can't place where the problem could be. is there something I ought to do that I am missing?